# Direct access to bitarray from cython

Tags: indexing, cython, bitarray

I can access **bitarray** bits with slice syntax..

```
b = bitarray(10)
b[5]
```

How would I access an element directly ?

Similar to the way I can directly access **array** elements:

```
ary.data.as_ints[5]
```

instead of :

```
ary[5]
```

I'm asking because when I tried this for **array** in some scenarios I got 20-30 fold speedup.

---

I found what I need to get access to, but don't know how !

[bitarray.h](https://github.com/ilanschnell/bitarray/blob/da56b8de778781344b160385263bd7362162a8a0/bitarray/bitarray.h)

look at getbit() and setbit().

How can I access them from Cython ?

---

current speeds

```
Shape: (10000, 10000)
VSize: 100.00Mil
Mem: 12207.03kb, 11.92mb
                
----------------------
sa[5,5]=1
108 ns +- 0.451 ns per loop (mean +- std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
sa[5,5]
146 ns +- 37.1 ns per loop (mean +- std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
sa[100:120,100:120]
34.8 µs +- 7.39 µs per loop (mean +- std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
sa[:100,:100]
614 µs +- 135 µs per loop (mean +- std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
sa[[0,1,2],[0,1,2]]
1.11 µs +- 301 ns per loop (mean +- std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
sa.sum()
6.74 ms +- 1.82 ms per loop (mean +- std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
sa.sum(axis=0)
9.92 ms +- 2.49 ms per loop (mean +- std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
sa.sum(axis=1)
646 ms +- 42.4 ms per loop (mean +- std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
sa.mean()
5.17 ms +- 160 µs per loop (mean +- std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
sa.mean(axis=0)
12.8 ms +- 2.5 ms per loop (mean +- std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
sa.mean(axis=1)
730 ms +- 25.1 ms per loop (mean +- std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
sa[[9269, 5484, 2001, 8881, 30, 9567, 7654, 3034, 4901, 552],:],
6.87 ms +- 1.2 ms per loop (mean +- std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
sa[:,[1417, 157, 9793, 1300, 2339, 2439, 2925, 3980, 4550, 5100]],
9.88 ms +- 1.56 ms per loop (mean +- std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
sa[[9269, 5484, 2001, 8881, 30, 9567, 7654, 3034, 4901, 552],[1417, 157, 9793, 1300, 2339, 2439, 2925, 3980, 4550, 5100]],
6.59 µs +- 1.78 µs per loop (mean +- std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
sa[[9269, 5484, 2001, 8881, 30, 9567, 7654, 3034, 4901, 552],:].sum(axis=1),
466 ms +- 121 ms per loop (mean +- std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Does your bitarray come from https://pypi.org/project/bitarray/? That site implies that they support the buffer protocol so they should work with typed memoryviews.

Comment: its the same bitarray .. isn't TMV indirect access ... as  far as i remember it is slower on arrays than direct access (which is compiled down to pointers i think).. will try to figure TMV and test it ..

Comment: I wouldn't expect typed memoryviews to be significantly slower than direct access (at least after you've turned off boundschecking and wraparound)

Comment: can't figure out how to set up TMV on BITS !

Comment: Probably `cdef unsigned char[::1] bitarrayview = bitarray`? Access it it will be a byte at a time rather than a bit at a time

Comment: i suspected that too.. would probably mapping it to 32 or 64 bit type be faster ? on the other hand get/set bit mask for bit access will be easier to manage !!!

Comment: I'd guess very slightly faster. But probably not enough that it's worth the extra effort

Comment: I advise you to use a Numpty array of `np.uint8` and use a *view* on it if you want a fast code (although it will be a bit cumber some to extract/set bits). Using `np.uint8` or `np.uint64` whill likely not make the code faster if it is *SIMD-friendly*. Having a SIMD-friendly code should make it much faster because of compiler *auto-vectorization*. Note that using pointers and allocations works too but there is more chance for the final code to contain memory leaks and bugs.

Comment: i'm using big arrays 10000x10000 to 50000x50000 i.e. 11mb to 300mb .. tried my own COO bit&float16 format .. at most 3-4 times faster than scipy and are good for less than 1/32 or 1/16 sparsity.. i expect to need ~10% sparsity .. only bitarray so far is a good compromise on speed,memory >>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using typed memoryviews (which lets you access chunks of 8 bits) and then using bitwise-and operations to access those bits. That's definitely the easiest and most "native" way to Cython.

```
cimport cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def sum_bits1(ba):
    cdef unsigned char[::1] ba_view = ba
    cdef int count = 0
    cdef Py_ssize_t n
    cdef unsigned char val
    for n in range(len(ba)):
        idx = n//8
        subidx = 1 << (n % 8)
        val = ba_view[idx] & subidx
        if val:
            count += 1
    return count
```

If you want to use it `getbit` and `setbit` functions defined in "bitarray.h" then you just define them as cdef extern functions. You need to find the path to "bitarray.h". It's probably in your local pip install directory somewhere. I've put the full path in the file but a better solution would be to specify an include path in setup.py.

```
cdef extern from "<path to home>/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bitarray/bitarray.h":
    ctypedef struct bitarrayobject:
        pass # we don't need to know the details
    
    ctypedef class bitarray.bitarray [object bitarrayobject]:
        pass
    
    int getbit(bitarray, int)
        
def sum_bits2(bitarray ba):
    cdef int count = 0
    cdef Py_ssize_t n
    for n in range(len(ba)):
        if getbit(ba, n):
            count += 1
    return count
```

To test it (and compare against a simple Python only version):

```
def sum_bits_naive(ba):
    count = 0
    for n in range(len(ba)):
        if ba[n]:
            count += 1
    return count

def test_funcs():
    from bitarray import bitarray
    
    ba = bitarray("110010"*10000)
    print(sum_bits1(ba), sum_bits2(ba), sum_bits_naive(ba))
    from timeit import timeit
    globs = dict(globals())
    globs.update(locals())
    print(timeit("sum_bits1(ba)", globals=globs, number=1000))
    print(timeit("sum_bits2(ba)", globals=globs, number=1000))
    print(timeit("sum_bits_naive(ba)", globals=globs, number=1000))
```

gives

```
(30000, 30000, 30000)
0.069798200041987
0.09307677199831232
1.3518586970167235
```

i.e. the memoryview version is the best.

Comment: i'm getting :  ....from bitarray import *
TypeError: Cannot overwrite C type bitarray  ....  what I'm doing wrong

Comment: `from bitarray import bitarray` works. I'd suggest using that rather than `import *`. I don't know why `import *` is an issue but it doesn't seem worth spending too much time on